# OpenCart 1.5.3 IE cannot work payment method in checkout page

Tags: popup, colorbox, opencart

The "continue" button on the checkout page under delivery details doesn't work. But the ‘billing details’ continue button and all other always seems to work. When click on the button, the waiting GIF is loaded and nothing happen.. When I comment out below script then it seems to be fine in all browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$('.colorbox').colorbox({
    width:640,
    height:480
});
//-->
</script>
```

I want to show the Terms & Conditions in popup..I didn't get popup when I comment the above code and it shows in another page.

Comment: Can you tell your URL? Are you using default template?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the tabs. I resolved the issue by placing the call in a document ready jquery container.(http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

The problem for me was that the JS in IE was trying to load before the element had rendered.